# Thin on dotcloud

Tags: ruby, thin, dotcloud

I have tried to install Thin on dotcloud, following the [official document](http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/ruby/thin/), but i failed.
"Thin:up..." appears on the cli, but I can't see it running by opening the url of the webapp
P.S. I don't run thin with ruby workers, is it relevant?

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial predates the "custom service"; it should be fairly easy to come up with something much better by leveraging on https://github.com/dotcloud/ruby-on-dotcloud.

*Edit:* I wrote a new Thin recipe; it is much simpler than the previous one, now that we have fixed some discrepancies in the `ruby-worker` service to make it more similar to the others. It's available there: https://github.com/jpetazzo/thin-on-dotcloud

Comment: @PatrickPang The link the jpetazzo linked above, describes the custom service for ruby. Feel free to contact support to get more information about the custom services. http://help.dotcloud.com

Answer (score 1):

You could also install thin from here: https://github.com/jpetazzo/thin

I got it to work with 4 very simple commands.

1. Clone the repository

   `$ git clone git://github.com/jpetazzo/thin.git`
2. Go into the root directory

   `$ cd thin`
3. Create the Thin stack

   `$ dotcloud create thin`
4. Push the Thin code to dotCloud

   `$ dotcloud push thin`

This did the trick for me.